# SQL Server : how to get DISTINCT COUNT for every GROUP

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I have a table like this:

[image]

I would like to get the distinct counts for every GROUP:

[image]

How to get the result? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select group,
       sum(case when location = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as a,
       sum(case when location = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as b,
       sum(case when location = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as c
from t
group by group;
```

Note that `group` is a very poor name for a column because it is a SQL reserved word.